# On some devices, posts (an array of documents) initially shows as empty when it isn't

Tags: arrays, swift, swiftui

I have a function to fetch posts from the people you follow and if it finds posts from the people you follow, it will show those posts, if it doesn't find posts, it will show a banner with a bunch of random posts. On one device (iPhone 13 Pro Max) the initial launch shows as random posts (even though this person has posts from the people she follows) then when she pulls up to refresh (calling the same `fetchfollowingposts` function) it fetches her actual following posts. This happens every time the app is closed and reopened.

**FeedViewModel**

```
import FirebaseAuth
import SwiftUI

class FeedViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var followingPosts = [Post]()
    @Published var posts = [Post]()
    @Published var newPost = false
    @Published var state: FeedState = .loading
    let service = FeedService()
    
    enum FeedState {
        case loading
        case loaded
        case empty
    }
    
    init() {
        fetchFollowingPosts()
    }
    
    func fetchFollowingPosts() {
        guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        
        service.fetchFollowingPosts(forUid: uid) { posts in
            if posts.count > 0 {
                self.followingPosts = posts
                self.state = .loaded
            } else {
                self.fetchAllPosts()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func fetchAllPosts() {
        service.fetchAllPosts { posts in
            self.posts = posts
            self.state = .empty
        }
    }
}
```

**FeedView**

```
import SwiftUI

struct FeedView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = FeedViewModel()
    @State var uploadedSuccess = false
    @State var didDeletePost = false
    @State var isShowingReportToast = false
    @EnvironmentObject var authViewModel: AuthViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 0) {
            
            Image("logo")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 48, height: 54)
            
            switch viewModel.state {
            case .loading:
                Spacer()
                ProgressView()
                Spacer()
            case .loaded:
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    PullToRefresh(coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                        viewModel.fetchFollowingPosts()
                    }
                    LazyVStack (spacing: 24) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.followingPosts) { post in
                            
                            FeedCell(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post), isShowingReportToast: $isShowingReportToast, didDeletePost: $didDeletePost)
                        }
                    }
                }.coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
                
            case .empty:
                ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                    
                    PullToRefresh(coordinateSpaceName: "pullToRefresh") {
                        viewModel.fetchFollowingPosts()
                    }
                    Group {
                        Divider()
                        VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 12) {
                            Image("wave")
                                .renderingMode(.template)
                                .resizable()
                                .frame(width: 36, height: 36)
                                .foregroundColor(.accentColor).opacity(0.25)
                            VStack (alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
                                Text("Welcome")
                                    .font(Font.headline)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.label))
                                
                                Text("Follow your friends to see their recommendations.")
                                    .font(Font.subheadline)
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(.darkGray))
                            }
                        }
                        .padding()
                        
                        Divider()
                    }
                    
                    
                    LazyVStack(spacing: 24) {
                        ForEach(viewModel.posts.shuffled().prefix(10)) { post in
                            FeedCell(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post), isShowingReportToast: $isShowingReportToast, didDeletePost: $didDeletePost)
                        }
                    }
                }.coordinateSpace(name: "pullToRefresh")
            }
        }
        .toast(isShowing: $isShowingReportToast, text: "Thank you! We received your report.")
        .onChange(of: didDeletePost) { newValue in
            viewModel.fetchFollowingPosts()
        }
        .onChange(of: authViewModel.uploadedSuccess) { newValue in
            viewModel.fetchFollowingPosts()
        }
    }
}
```

**FeedService**

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift

struct FeedService {

    func fetchFollowingPosts(forUid uid: String, completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
        var posts = [Post]()
        
        COLLECTION_FOLLOWING.document(uid).collection("user-following")
            .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                guard let documents = snapshot?.documents else { return }
                
                    documents.forEach { doc in
                        let userId = doc.documentID
                        
                        COLLECTION_POSTS.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userId)
                        
                            .getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
                                if let documents = snapshot?.documents {
                                    
                                    let post = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
                                    posts.append(contentsOf: post)
                                    completion(posts.sorted(by: { $0.timestamp.dateValue() > $1.timestamp.dateValue()
                                    }))
                                } else {
                                    print("error fetching following posts")
                                }
                            }
                    }
            }
    }
    
    func fetchAllPosts(completion: @escaping([Post]) -> Void) {
        COLLECTION_POSTS.getDocuments { snapshot, _ in
            if let documents = snapshot?.documents {
                let posts = documents.compactMap({ try? $0.data(as: Post.self) })
                completion(posts)
            } else {
                print("error fetching all posts")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to narrow down the issue. One way is to write Unit tests testing your model. Or, let your ViewModel receive an Environment struct containing a dependency "FeedService". This can be an essential of a protocol `FeedServiceProtocol` or may be a struct containing closures. You can fake this and test its behaviour. Utilise the SwiftUI environment feature to pass through an env struct, which is set up at App location, to a special view in your use case which reads the env and passes it through as parameter to your FeedView which creates the ViewModel. Then preview it with mocked data.